# How to clear garbage in PHP 4

Tags: memory-leaks, php4

I have written an application. But there is an issue of memory overflowing. Is there a way to clear all garbage values in PHP 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think more information about your specific case and environment (I am just guessing that you are running PHP from a web server and not CLI) is needed. And you should look through your entire code yourself for places that can be optimized.

As you probably know, garbage collection is not a part of PHP 4. Check out [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) and http://www.obdev.at/developers/articles/00002.html for some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is memory overflow. You can use:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M'); //or the quantity of memory you need
```

This will expand the default memory used on the httpd.conf for that script.

Note: I'm not sure if it works on php 4 but, give it a try.